# Trying to create a simple form in python with user input

Tags: python, loops, date, dictionary, nested

I am a newbie to Python, and trying to create an input form using a nested dictionary with the following flow, but really struggling to cope with how to code having multiple values (as a list) that can be associated per topic within the dictionary:

Steps

1. Ask the user to input a topic / issue which is stored in an empty dictionary
2. Immediately after entering a topic / problem, prompt user to enter an action to resolve the problem, associate it with a due date entered by the user to complete by,  and then linked to the topic / issue (key) created in step 1 as value to that key
3. Prompt user to add another action to the same topic if required with y/n or move to add another topic
4. add another topic / issue if required
5. print the dictionary with the topic / issues (keys) and associated values or multiple values with due dates.

Note  I have not added due dates, and code to loop through the completed dictionary to list problems / actions with the due dates to amend, delete or change.

Any help really appreciated!! :)

here is a sample of my incomplete code:

```
problems = {}

problems_open = True
actions_open = True
while problems_open:
    issue = input("\nPlease enter a topic / problem? ")
    while actions_open:
        action = input("What action are you going to take for this topic? ")
        problems[issue] = action
        repeat = input("Would you like to add another action y/n?")
        if repeat == 'n':
            actions_open = False
        """ This is not appending multiple actions to the dictionary problems, just the 
        last entry """
        """ Not sure how to add a due date to each action """

    repeat = input("Would you like to add another topic / problem? ")
    if repeat == "n":
        problems_open = False

print("\n--- List of problems and actions with dates ---")
for issue, action in problems.items():
    print("The problem: " + issue + " has " + "the following actions: " + action)
```

Comment: Could you show an example of what the final dictionary should look like?

Comment: something like this, but obviously the number of problems and associated actions will vary from 1 to n:

problems = {'user_problem1': ['user_action1', 'user_action2', 'user_action3'...],
                   'user_probelm2': ['user_action1],
                   'user_problem2': ['user_action1', user_action2],
                   'user_problem3': ['user_action1']
                  }

I would also like to add and associate a date for each action within the dictionary, but not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code were the nested lists. The problem with nested lists is, that you can't iterate through them with numbers. That means to identify the specific value in the list would be very difficult.
The solution is to use lists (the ones with the square brackets).

I made a working code for your problem:

```
problems = []
actions = []

problems_open = True
actions_open = True
offset = -1
while problems_open:
    issue = input("\nPlease enter a topic / problem? ")
    problems.append(issue)
    while actions_open == True:
        action = input("What action are you going to take for this topic? ") 
        actions.append(action)  
        actions_open = False

    repeat = input("Would you like to add another topic / problem? y/n ")
    if repeat == "n":
        problems_open = False
    elif repeat == "y":
        problems_open = True
        actions_open = True
    
print("\n--- List of problems and actions with dates ---")
for problems, actions in zip(problems, actions):
        print("The problem: " + problems + " has " + "the following actions: " + actions)
```

The only difference in this code is that you are not asked multiple times for taking another action on one problem again. I just made a working list for you. I hope it helped.

Comment: Thx for  your help.  This helps to get me further along.  I didn't realise you cannot do this with a nested dictionary.  I still need to be able to have more than one action per problem and an associated due date to complete each action.  Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @Ed Waldheim No problem. I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as the best answer so other people with the same problem as you can use it.

Comment: I thank you for your contribution and I have tried your code but on further analysis, it works in a slightly different way to the one I intended, as I still need to be able to have more than one action associated directly with a particular problem that a user can enter, and come back to to enter more actions.  I am still not sure how this can be achieved using lists and / or dictionaries...  Essentially it is a task scheduler comprising an issue and associated action(s) that a user can add, then amend, and delete whilst associating a due date to be done by per action.

Comment: I mean what you still have to do add the part, where the user is asked to take further actions and attach that value to the first one seperated by a comma. I actually coded that before I sent this answer but I didn't have time to finish the whole code because of the loops and so on. As I said, for instance when I'm asked to take further actions or not and I answer with "y" and then type in the actions, all you have to do is to add that value TO the value in that specififc index you're in.  That means if you were in problems[1] then it's something like problems[1] = problems [1] + "," + repeat

Comment: If you have time, can you share your code for this?  I am still new at this, so trying to understand lists within lists.  Many thanks again.

Comment: I'll try to do it and share it with you as soon as possible. You're welcome.